# Value in amount column in csv file is getting inserted in another column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm getting a

> 1202 Extra column(s) found error

in Redshift when trying to load a simple CSV.

I tried below query as I had a csv file with an amount which has a comma.

```
COPY imtest.cloudchckr_test FROM 's3://imtestredshift/Cloudchckr/Cloudchecker_listcost_csv.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RedshiftAccessS3'
csv;
```

[image: Data]

[image: Result]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjNM4.png)

Comment: Please can you edit your post to show the DDL (create table) statement for your target table if you have one, and also include one or more of the source s3 file rows. make sure the error actually occurs with the example rows that you have included! Also please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. (Do not use images or links to images!)

Comment: The answer is quite obvious from your example. The comma in the 4th column (eg `$4,615.83`) is being interpreted as a comma that starts a new column. Are you processing a raw billing file that was provided by AWS, or are you saving the file from Excel? If you are saving from Excel, than you can change the format of that column to remove commas (and currency symbols) and it should work fine.

Comment: I have resolved the error 1202 Extra column(s) found  but value which have coma in csv is getting shift to next column

Comment: @JohnRotenstein im have the excel file which have the list cost for resellers and i have converted that file to CSV. Also , i have a file where in name column there is a comma i cannot afford to change the format.

Comment: @JonScott : please see create table statement Create table imtest.cloudchckr (
account varchar(15),
Name varchar(30),
Service varchar(30),
List_cost varchar(20)
);

Comment: change / mess about with excel until you get a nicer csv file. get values as float/interger without dollar signs or commas or quotes. And - in future avoid excel in your data processing pipelines if at all possible!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `csv` option, please see the last line of below command:

```
copy category
from 's3://mybucket/data/category_csv.txt' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole' 
csv;
```

If you have something other than `"` as quote character, then specify that as below:

```
csv quote as '%';
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reply.
im using csv in copy file.please see the copy command that im using 
COPY imtest.cloudchckr_test FROM 's3://imtestredshift/Cloudchckr/Cloudchecker_listcost_csv.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RedshiftAccessS3'
csv;

Comment: Hi 
Im using query editor to run these command.
is it due to query editor or really would be a issue in server as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is not `QOUTE` but its `comma(,)` for `integer` or `numeric` columns.
So you have two options to solve,

1. Pre-process in remove `comma(,)` from `numeric` columns.
2. You have to load it into `varchar` column and then copy and transform the data into `numeric` column.

There is `exactly` same use case as mentioned on [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#load-from-csv).

e.x. Table is having `varchar` columns, like below and even if you have data like below that includes `comma`, it will work `seamlessly`.

```
create table example(
salesid varchar(25) ,
listid varchar(25) ,
sellerid varchar(25) ,
buyerid integer );
```

And data like below with `comma(,)`.

```
"AAA","12,133","234,144","231"
"BBB","22,233",234244,"232"
"CCC","32,333","234,344","233"
"DDD","42,433",234444,"234"
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your help .
issue is resolved for numeric value. but what need to be done if there is comma (,) in a string ?

Comment: I have added screenshot of the file where name have comma (,)